# Ajax.Actionlink onBegin not canceling request with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have function that is called in "onBegin" ajax option of ajax.actionlink

```
function cancelAction() {
    $.ajax({
        data: { p: "test", z: "value" },
        url: '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "TestCtlr")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.do == 0) { 
                 // do something
            }

            else {
                alert("error message");
            }

        },

    }
    )}
return false;
}
```

When i click on link, alert with error message is shown, but actionlink continue to controller action, instead of breaking it.

Here's code for actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click here",//link text
  "Insert", // action name
  "Projects",  // controller
  new { poz = item.itemID.ToString() }, // route values 
  new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetID = "PrjDiv", OnBegin = "cancelAction", OnSuccess = "Initiate_Dialog" }, // ajax options
  new { @class = "openDialog", @id = item.idemID.ToString() } //htmlAttributes
  )
```

**Edit**

I changed code to match vekah's answer, and now it's working, except i can't get redirection to work.

I tried to put `$.ajax(this.url)` and `$.ajax(this.href)` instead of `//do something`, but it's not working...

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return false from your anonymous success ajax function.
And you want to return false from cancelAction.

You should delete those `return false;` and put it after the ajax declaration.

Edit:
Ok for code sample.

```
function cancelAction()
{
$.ajax({
        data: { p: "test", z: "value" },
        url: '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "TestCtlr")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.do == 0) {
// DO SOME REDIRECTION BECAUSE EVENT WILL BE PREVENT
 }
            else {
                alert("error message");
            }

        }
    });
return false;
}
```

Edit²: You got some syntax errors ! Is this your true code ? Do not the console throw you some errors ? (the end of your ajax looks strange, it should be something like : `});` as I correct in my code.

Comment: Any chance for a code sample? I'm new to js and jquery and stll trying to figure how things work...

Comment: Thanks for response, it works somehow, but can You tell me what to put in commented part, where redirect should go? 
again, js/jquery/web programming newbie...

Comment: It only depends on you.
What return false did ?
It prevents "normal" behaviour of your event.
For instance, if you click on a submit button of a form, the event is to send a request with the parameters of your form.
If you add a return false on click of this submit button, it won't submit the form.

With your code, I can't know what event is triggered, what you wanna do.
What is sure, is that you have to redo the default event, that you cancel. (submit form, redirect to the link they click on, make blur / focus an element etc ...)

Comment: Click on ajax.actionlink should check in database (onbegin) if there's record with parameters p and z (data) and if there's none, to call jquery ui dialog (Initiate_Dialog) to insert record in database.

Comment: You should not do this way.
This is way more complicate.

You should bind your actionlink, to the check.
When checkCallback is finished, you just should check what you have to check, and then to call that or this function.

Instead of directly bind your actionlink to the after check function.

Comment: You still can try something with jquery ajax events.
http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: Or i can add "async:   false" to $.ajax(), define new variable set to true or false, depending on controller action, and return this variable as function result. 
anyway, thanks for help.